# Detecting key-press in background in a Winforms project

Tags: c#, winforms, keypress, ctrl

I am doing a quiz like game (winforms) and I want to introduce the functionality of a cheat or easter egg. If I have a question in front of me and when I press a secret key (ex: Ctrl or other key) a label will show the right answer.

All the questions will show up on the same form, if this helps. The problem is that I can't find a simple and effective way of detecting a key on background.

Comment: Override the Form's ProcessCmdKey function.

Comment: You can get what you are searching for with the form KeyPreview property and the KeyDown event of the same form

Comment: Set your form's `KeyPreview` property to `true` and the handle the `KeyDown` / `KeyPress` events of your form

Comment: What do you mean with "on background"? As previous comments said using the usual mechanisms for keyboard input will work if the app is focused, but that sentence makes me think you want something different than regular keyboard input.

Answer (score 3):

You can `overdide` from `ProcessCmdKey`

**Example**

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
        switch (keyData)
        {
            case Keys.F1:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Great guys! It is working

let me put the code here for future help:

```
    private void FormName_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.ControlKey)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Test");
        }
    }
```